# Pull a name out of cell if date is greater than a cell

Tags: vba, excel, date

One of my software applications that tracks approvals puts all of the data into a single field and I'm trying to track if an individual is late to approve it, what their name is. The problem is there aren't a consistent number of approvals so there may be one, there may be 20. Below is an example of what the system returns.

> Approval history Status: Approved 06/11/12 04:01 AM  Submitted for approval by John Doe  06/13/12 04:20 AM  Approved by Steve Smith For some reason associated with 'Some name -- XYZ1 - Program'  06/13/12 04:20 AM  Approved by Steve Smith For some reason associated with 'Word:LS Other'  06/13/12 04:20 AM  Approved by Steve Smith For some reason associated with 'Another name:Product -- LMN1'  06/13/12 04:20 AM  Approved by Steve Smith For some reason associated with 'Random Different Name:Word -- QRS1'  06/13/12 04:26 AM  Approved by Mary Sue For some reason associated with 'Other Thing:Program -- DEF14'  06/13/12 04:26 AM  Approved by John Doe  Notes: Automatic approval: The approver is the same user as the submitter

I'm looking for a macro that will look through all the dates and compare them to a date in cell A1 and check if any are greater than cell A1.

For instance, if the date in A1 is "6/10/12" it should return the value "John Doe". If none of the dates are greater than cell A1, return blank. Sometimes the first 4 dates will all be less than A1, but the remaining ones will be greater. I would want the first date that is greater than A1.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: I'm thinking you could put all that in a row, via Text to Columns with a space delimiter. Then you can look through each cell, and if it's a date, pull the info in the cells two to the left of it.  [What have you tried so far](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: @BruceWayne At first I thought so too. But it seems that the names are not always at the same location. So, this would not work for `Steve Smith` and the date 06/13/12. Here, the name is wrapped in between text to the left and to the right of the name (as far as I can tell).

Comment: lol you asked this yesterday (now deleted) saying you know how to do it with a macro but wanted to see if you can do it via formula. Edit: i think it was @jnevill that commented that you should use macro, not formula.

Comment: Do you possibly have a list of people that you expect to be in that text? What kind of reasoning can we use to determine a name?  There's got to be some sort of logic, otherwise this can get pretty tricky, since the names and dates can seemingly appear anywhere.  There's no way to perhaps instead tweak your system that outputs that data, eh?

Comment: The list of names is variable depending on turnover so it's not completely defined. I was using the words "Approved by" and adjusting the position to the left to grab the date and then to the right to grab the name.

Comment: Will the names you are interested always follow "Approved by"?
Where will the above string be located? What do you want to do with the result you get out of the macro?

Answer (score 0):

As you are a little vague on what you want to do with the data you extract from the string, the following is my take on the problem. The original string is pasted into "B1" and the late approvers are saved into an array. A message box appears telling you who the first tardy approver was.

```
Sub GetDatesFromString()

Dim SubStrings() As String
Dim NameSplit() As String
Dim TimeSplit() As Date
Dim Approvers() As String
Dim index, UpperBound, ApproversIndex As Integer

SubStrings() = Split(Cells(1, 2), "M ")
UpperBound = UBound(SubStrings())
ReDim NameSplit(UpperBound)
ReDim TimeSplit(UpperBound)

ApproversIndex = 0
For index = 0 To UBound(SubStrings())
    If (Right(SubStrings(index), 1) = "A" Or Right(SubStrings(index), 1) = "P") Then
        SubStrings(index) = SubStrings(index) & "M"
    End If
    NameSplit() = Split(SubStrings(index), " ", 5)
    If (Right(SubStrings(index), 2) = "AM" Or Right(SubStrings(index), 2) = "PM") Then
        TimeSplit(index) = Right(SubStrings(index), 17)
        If ((TimeSplit(index) > 0) And (Left(SubStrings(index), 8) = "Approved")) Then
            If TimeSplit(index) > Cells(1, 1) Then
                ApproversIndex = ApproversIndex + 1
                ReDim Preserve Approvers(ApproversIndex)
                Approvers(ApproversIndex) = NameSplit(2) & " " & NameSplit(3) & " on " & TimeSplit(index)
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next index

If ApproversIndex > 0 Then
    MsgBox ("The first late approver was " & Approvers(1))
Else
    MsgBox ("There were no late approvers")
End If

End Sub
```

If the data isn't in a consistent format then the output may not be as expected.